# Calculate Percentage of YES/NO and find average

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to to get the percentage of Yes or No on the HTML Table from the response of the user from the questions of each month and then display the average percentage in the average in the average column of each month (For example if the the user selects 'no'for saving and 'yes' for over budget it should display the average
50% for the month of Jan) but all I'm getting is NaN% for each month . I tried creating a script of each month but shows the same result in average.

Then I trying to add all the Response Percent and get its average and display the average in the total average under total response.

HTML, CSS and JS:

```js
$(function() {
  mon_jan();
});

function mon_jan() {
  var target_span = $('#span1');
  count_yes_no(target_span);
}

function count_yes_no(spn) {
  var yes = 0;
  var no = 0;
  var l = 0;
  spn.find('select').each(function() {

    if ($(this).val() == 'Yes') {
      yes++;
    }
    if ($(this).val() == 'No') {
      no++;
    }
    l++;
  });

  // update count values summary
  $('.cnt-yes').text(yes);
  $('.cnt-no').text(no);

  $('.len').text(parseInt(l));
  $('.cnt-percent-y').text((yes * 100 / l).toFixed(2));
  $('.cnt-percent-n').text((no * 100 / l).toFixed(2));
}




$(function() {
  mon_feb();
});

function mon_feb() {
  var target_span = $('#span1');
  count_yes_no(target_span);
}

function count_yes_no(spn) {
  var yes = 0;
  var no = 0;
  var l = 0;
  spn.find('select').each(function() {

    if ($(this).val() == 'Yes') {
      yes++;
    }
    if ($(this).val() == 'No') {
      no++;
    }
    l++;
  });

  // update count values summary
  $('.cnt-yes').text(yes);
  $('.cnt-no').text(no);

  $('.len').text(parseInt(l));
  $('.cnt-percent-y').text((yes * 100 / l).toFixed(2));
  $('.cnt-percent-n').text((no * 100 / l).toFixed(2));
}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <h1>Finding Average -- Excel Spreadsheet to get similiar results</h1>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Jan</th>
        <th>Feb</th>
        <th>Mar</th>
        <th>Apr</th>
        <th>May</th>
        <th>Jun</th>
        <th>Jul</th>
        <th>Aug</th>
        <th>Sept</th>
        <th>Oct</th>
        <th>Nov</th>
        <th>Dec</th>
        <th>Total Average</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <span id="span1">
                  <td>Savings</td>
                  <td>
                      <select onchange="mon_jan();">
                          <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                          <option value="No">No</option>
                      </select>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                      <select onchange="mon_feb();">
                          <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                          <option value="No">No</option>
                      </select>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                      <select onchange="ch_sel();">
                          <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                          <option value="No">No</option>
                      </select>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                      <select onchange="ch_sel();">
                          <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                          <option value="No">No</option>
                      </select>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                      <select onchange="ch_sel();">
                          <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                          <option value="No">No</option>
                      </select>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                      <select onchange="ch_sel();">
                          <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                          <option value="No">No</option>
                      </select>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                      <select onchange="ch_sel();">
                          <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                          <option value="No">No</option>
                      </select>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                      <select onchange="ch_sel();">
                          <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                          <option value="No">No</option>
                      </select>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                      <select onchange="ch_sel();">
                          <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                          <option value="No">No</option>
                      </select>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                      <select onchange="ch_sel();">
                          <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                          <option value="No">No</option>
                      </select>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                      <select onchange="ch_sel();">
                          <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                          <option value="No">No</option>
                      </select>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                      <select onchange="ch_sel();">
                          <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                          <option value="No">No</option>
                      </select>
                  </td>
              </span>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Over Budget</td>
        <td>
          <select onchange="mon_jan();">
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select onchange="mon_feb();">
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select onchange="ch_sel();">
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select onchange="ch_sel();">
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select onchange="ch_sel();">
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select onchange="ch_sel();">
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select onchange="ch_sel();">
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select onchange="ch_sel();">
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select onchange="ch_sel();">
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select onchange="ch_sel();">
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select onchange="ch_sel();">
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select onchange="ch_sel();">
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <td>Response Percent</td>
      <td>
        <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
```

Comment: I can't find the issue with your HTML code but there is certainly one. The span is rendering right after the h1 for some reason. Your missing closing body tag doesn't solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is that span is not a valid child element of a tr. Removing the span and giving the id to the tr would probably work better.

My jQuery is pretty rusty but I took a stab at a partially working solution in case it helps:

```js
const $select_rows = $('.select_row');
const $percent_row = $('.percent_row');

function update_column(col_index) {
  const child_index = col_index + 2; // 1 indexed plus 1 for row heading
  const $selects = $select_rows.find('td:nth-child(' + child_index + ') select');
 
  if($selects.length) {
    let yes_count = 0;
    $selects.each(function() {
      if($(this).val() == 'Yes') {
        yes_count++;
      }
    });

    $percent_row.find('td:nth-child(' + child_index + ') .cnt-percent-y').text((yes_count * 100 / $selects.length).toFixed(2));
  }
}

function setup() {
  $select_rows.each(function() {
    $(this).find('select').each(function(index) {
      const col_index = index;
      
      $(this).change(function() {
        update_column(col_index);
      });
      
      update_column(col_index);
    });
  });
}

setup();
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <h1>Finding Average -- Excel Spreadsheet to get similiar results</h1>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Jan</th>
        <th>Feb</th>
        <th>Mar</th>
        <th>Apr</th>
        <th>May</th>
        <th>Jun</th>
        <th>Jul</th>
        <th>Aug</th>
        <th>Sept</th>
        <th>Oct</th>
        <th>Nov</th>
        <th>Dec</th>
        <th>Total Average</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Savings</td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="No">No</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="No">No</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="No">No</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="No">No</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="No">No</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="No">No</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="No">No</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="No">No</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="No">No</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="No">No</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="No">No</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="No">No</option>
            </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Over Budget</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr class="percent_row">
        <td>Response Percent</td>
        <td>
          <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
```

Comment: Your a life saver Ben thank you so much for helping. I went over the code so many times but couldnt fix it. Thank you once again

Comment: I have one question how can i save the response user enters or selects so the next time the user opens the webpage it shows the same data. so the user can only edit any changes if they want